# Faster implementation of fractional encoding (similar to one-hot encoding)

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, pandas-groupby, one-hot-encoding

## Problem Statement

Create an efficient fractional encoding (similar to a one-hot encoding) for a ragged list of components and corresponding compositions.

### Toy Example

Take a composite material with the following `class: ingredient` combinations:

- [Filler](https://www.totalboat.com/2021/02/11/when-and-how-to-use-an-epoxy-filler/): Colloidal Silica (`filler_A`)
- Filler: Milled Glass Fiber (`filler_B`)
- [Resin](https://www.thomasnet.com/articles/plastics-rubber/types-of-resins/): Polyurethane (`resin_A`)
- Resin: Silicone (`resin_B`)
- Resin: Epoxy (`resin_C`)

### Dummy Data

```py
components = np.array(
    [
        ["filler_A", "filler_B", "resin_C"],
        ["filler_A", "resin_B"],
        ["filler_A", "filler_B", "resin_B"],
        ["filler_A", "resin_B", "resin_C"],
        ["filler_B", "resin_A", "resin_B"],
        ["filler_A", "resin_A"],
        ["filler_B", "resin_A", "resin_B"],
    ],
    dtype=object,
)

compositions = np.array(
    [
        [0.4, 0.4, 0.2],
        [0.5, 0.5],
        [0.5, 0.3, 0.2],
        [0.5, 0.5, 0.0],
        [0.6, 0.4, 0.0],
        [0.6, 0.4],
        [0.6, 0.2, 0.2],
    ],
    dtype=object,
)
```

### Desired Output

`X_train`:

```py
   filler_A  filler_B  resin_A  resin_B  resin_C
0       0.4       0.4      0.0      0.0      0.2
1       0.5       0.0      0.0      0.5      0.0
2       0.5       0.3      0.0      0.2      0.0
3       0.5       0.0      0.0      0.5      0.0
4       0.0       0.6      0.4      0.0      0.0
5       0.6       0.0      0.4      0.0      0.0
6       0.0       0.6      0.2      0.2      0.0
```

## What I've tried

I have a slow `fractional_encode` implementation, a `fractional_decode` for reference, and basic usage.

### My (Slow) Implementation

After struggling with making a faster implementation, I resorted to making a slow, 2-level nested `for` loop implementation of creating the one-hot-like fractional or prevalence encoding.

```py
def fractional_encode(components, compositions, drop_last=False):
    """Fractionally encode components and compositions similar to one-hot encoding.

    In one-hot encoding, components are assigned a "1" if it exists for a particular
    compound, and a "0" if it does not. However, this ignores the case where the
    composition (i.e. the fractional prevalence) of each component is known. For
    example, NiAl is 50% Ni and 50% Al. This function computes the fractional components
    (albeit manually using for loops) where instead of a "1" or a "0", the corresponding
    fractional prevalence is assigned (e.g. 0.2, 0.5643, etc.).

    Parameters
    ----------
    components : list of lists of strings or numbers
        The components that make up the compound for each compound. If strings, then
        each string corresponds to a category. If numbers, then each number must
        uniquely describe a particular category.
    compositions : list of lists of floats
        The compositions of each component that makes up the compound for each compound.
    drop_last : bool, optional
        Whether to drop the last component. This is useful since compositions are
        constrained to sum to one, and therefore there is `n_components - 1` degrees of freedom, by default False

    Returns
    -------
    X_train : 2D array
        Fractionally encoded matrix.

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        Components and compositions should have the same shape.

    See also
    --------
    "Convert jagged array to Pandas dataframe" https://stackoverflow.com/a/63496196/13697228
    """
    # lengths, unique components, and initialization
    n_compounds = len(components)
    unique_components = np.unique(list(flatten(components)))
    n_unique = len(unique_components)
    X_train = np.zeros((n_compounds, n_unique))

    for i in range(n_compounds):
        # unpack
        component = components[i]
        composition = compositions[i]

        # lengths
        n_component = len(component)
        n_composition = len(composition)

        if n_component != n_composition:
            raise ValueError("Components and compositions should have the same shape")

        for j in range(n_unique):
            # unpack
            unique_component = unique_components[j]
            if unique_component in component:
                # assign
                idx = component.index(unique_component)
                X_train[i, j] = composition[idx]
    if drop_last:
        # remove last column: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6710726/13697228
        X_train = np.delete(X_train, -1, axis=1)
    X_train = pd.DataFrame(data=X_train, columns=unique_components)
    return X_train
```

### An Inverse Implementation (Decoding)

For reference, I also made a function for decoding `X_train`, which uses higher-level operations:

```py
def fractional_decode(X_train):
    """Fractionally decode components and compositions similar to one-hot encoding.

    In one-hot encoding, components are assigned a "1" if it exists for a particular
    compound, and a "0" if it does not. However, this ignores the case where the
    composition (i.e. the fractional prevalence) of each component is known. For
    example, NiAl is 50% Ni and 50% Al. This function decodes the fractional encoding
    where instead of "1" or a "0", the corresponding fractional prevalence is used (e.g. 0.2, 0.5643, etc.).

    Parameters
    ----------
    X_train : DataFrame
        Fractionally encoded matrix (similar to a one-hot encoded matrix).

    last_dropped : bool, optional
        Whether the last component is already dropped. This is useful since compositions
        are constrained to sum to one, and therefore there is `n_components - 1` degrees
        of freedom. If `drop_last` from `fractional_encode` is set to True, and you want
        to decode, set to True. By default False

    Returns
    -------
    components : list of lists of strings or numbers
        The components that make up the compound for each compound. If strings, then
        each string corresponds to a category. If numbers, then each number must
        uniquely describe a particular category.
    compositions : list of lists of floats
        The compositions of each component that makes up the compound for each compound.

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        Components and compositions should have the same shape.
    """
    # lengths, unique components, and sparse matrix attributes
    unique_components = X_train.columns
    n_unique = len(unique_components)
    sparse_mat = coo_matrix(X_train.values)
    row_ids, col_ids = sparse_mat.row, sparse_mat.col
    idx_pairs = list(zip(row_ids, col_ids))
    comps = sparse_mat.data

    # lookup dictionaries to replace col_ids with components
    component_lookup = {
        component_idx: unique_component
        for (component_idx, unique_component) in zip(range(n_unique), unique_components)
    }

    # lookup dictionaries to replace idx_pairs with compositions
    composition_lookup = {idx_pair: comp for (idx_pair, comp) in zip(idx_pairs, comps)}

    # contains placeholder col_ids and idx_pairs which will get replaced by components
    # and compositions, respectively
    tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(
        data=[(idx_pair[1], idx_pair) for idx_pair in idx_pairs],
        columns=["component", "composition"],
    )

    # NOTE: component_lookup should be mapped before composition_lookup
    tmp_df.component = tmp_df.component.map(component_lookup)
    tmp_df.composition = tmp_df.composition.map(composition_lookup)

    # add a row_id column to use for grouping into ragged entries
    cat_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(row_ids, columns=["row_id"]), tmp_df], axis=1)

    # combine components and compositions compound-wise
    df = (
        cat_df.reset_index()
        .groupby(by="row_id")
        .agg({"component": lambda x: tuple(x), "composition": lambda x: tuple(x)})
    )

    # extract and convert to ragged lists
    components, compositions = [df[key] for key in ["component", "composition"]]
    components = list(components)
    compositions = list(compositions)

    return components, compositions
```

### Example Usage

```py
X_train = fractional_encode(components, compositions)
components, compositions = fractional_decode(X_train)
```

### Question

What is a faster implementation of `fractional_encode`?

Answer (score 2):

A solution that initializes an array with zeros then updates the fields:

```
columns = sorted(list(set(sum(list(components), []))))
data = np.zeros((len(components), len(columns)))

for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    for component, composition in zip(components[i], compositions[i]):
        j = columns.index(component)
        data[i, j] = composition

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)
```

Output:

```
   filler_A  filler_B  resin_A  resin_B  resin_C
0       0.4       0.4      0.0      0.0      0.2
1       0.5       0.0      0.0      0.5      0.0
2       0.5       0.3      0.0      0.2      0.0
3       0.5       0.0      0.0      0.5      0.0
4       0.0       0.6      0.4      0.0      0.0
5       0.6       0.0      0.4      0.0      0.0
6       0.0       0.6      0.2      0.2      0.0
```

Comment: Very succinct. Thank you!